# Debug Android Native Code without source

Tags: ida, debugging, gdb, android

Id like to debug (to log function calls) native ARM Android Code in a shared library. So far I got no source and tried to disassemble it with IDA, but its hard to track all the calls down to a specific function.
So I came up with IDA's `android_server`, which didnt work(*not breaking on breakpoints, pausing takes me always to the same loop, cant step through*) and Android NDK's `gbdserver` using as remote GDB Debugger in IDA based on that http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=35602033&postcount=5 which results in the same. Using NDK's `gdbserver` and cli `gdb` didnt work, cause it requires the (source) project folder.
Thats why Id like to ask if there is  a way to debug native code w/o source or tracking down the calls is possible?

*(in this case nearly all of the app runs on native code/the funcs Id like to track arent called directly over JNI)*

Comment: You don't need the source to run gdb. There are some commands that rely on source/symbols, like disassemble, but you can use commands like x/20i <address> instead. My answer to http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4216/set-breakpoint-on-shared-library/4221#4221 might help you.